# How to get more information about a mountpoint

Tags: mount, mountpoint

I have had some problems with ISPConfig this morning which are fixed by now, however I noticed this mounts:

```
/dev/sda2 on /var/www/clients/client1/web1/log type ext4 (rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered,jqfmt=vfsv0,usrjquota=quota.user,grpjquota=quota.group,_netdev)
```

There are many of them, for every `client` and `web` there is.

This looked weird. How could ISPConfig mount `/dev/sda2` on so many different folders and yet, they don't share their content. Also, `sda2` was mounted on `/`.

I got *some* information though googeling and found `/proc/self/mountinfo` gives some more helpful informations:

```
83 24 8:2 /var/log/ispconfig/httpd/example.net /var/www/clients/client1/web1/log rw,relatime shared:1 - ext4 /dev/sda2 rw,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered,jqfmt=vfsv0,usrjquota=quota.user,grpjquota=quota.group
```

Now we're getting somewhere. Seems like, ISPConfig mounts a subfolder of `sda2` (namely `/var/log/ispconfig/httpd/example.net`) to `/var/www/clients/client1/web1/log`.

I don't know *why* ISPConfig does this, if someone knows, feel free to comment on the question, but my question is:

**Is there a better way to get as much information about a mountpoint as possible?**

`/proc/self/mountinfo` is good, it prints lot of information, but it's hard to read, I'd need to remember what each column means to understand it. It's nice for programs to parse but not so nice for humans to read.

Comment: How about `findmnt` source: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/24182/how-to-get-the-complete-and-exact-list-of-mounted-filesystems-in-linux

Answer (score 1):

The command

```
df -h
```

of just

```
df
```

gives you some informations

Comment: How is this better than the output OP already has? And `df` is about filesystem, not mount points.

Answer (score 0):

`mount` with no parameters, will list mount information.

Comment: The first listing in the question looks exactly like the output of `mount`.